Kalman Filter to estimate height and vertical velocity using a barometer
I try to derive the equation system to estimate the height and the vertical velocity using a barometer, same as in [3]
I have the following time continuous system
$\frac{dx}{dt} = G \cdot x(t) + V \cdot v(t)$
and
$y = H \cdot x(t) + w(t)$
$x = \begin{bmatrix}
   height \\
   \text{vertical velocity}
\end {bmatrix}$,
$ G = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0
\end {bmatrix}$
,
$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0
\end {bmatrix}$,
$V = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   v_a
\end {bmatrix}$
and y is the measured height
when I discretize this system with the van Loan Method described in [1], [2] or [4]
$\hat{G} = \begin{bmatrix}
   -G & VWV^T \\
   0 & G^T
\end {bmatrix} \cdot \Delta t$,
$G_{exp} = e^{\hat{G}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   ... & G_n^{-1}C_{V_n} \\
   0 & G_n^T
\end {bmatrix}$
I get $G_n^T$ by transposing the lower right part and $C_{V_n}$ by multiplying the upper right by $G_n^T$
$C_{V_n} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\Delta t^3}{3} & \frac{\Delta t^2}{2} \\
   \frac{\Delta t^2}{2} & \Delta t
\end {bmatrix} \cdot v_a^2$
and
$ G_n = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & dt \\
   0 & 1
\end {bmatrix}$
But when looking into [3] Q looks different (a delta t is missing on each entry):
$$
Q = \sigma_u^2\,
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\Delta t^4}{4} & \frac{\Delta t^3}{2} \\
\frac{\Delta t^3}{2} & \Delta t^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
When calculating $e^{G\cdot \Delta t}$ I get
$ G_n = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & dt \\
   0 & 1
\end {bmatrix}$
which is the same as above and
$V_n = \int_0^{\Delta t} G_n V dt$, $C_{V_n} = V \cdot W \cdot V^T$ I get also the same as Q.
Why don't I get the same result with the van Loan method and others?
Here is the code from maxima
G :  matrix([0, 1], [0, 0]);
H: matrix([1, 0]);
V: matrix([0], [v_v]);
W: 1;

/* discretizing */
Gn: matrixexp(G * dt);
Vk:  integrate(Gn.V, dt);
CV_n_alternative: Vk.transpose(Vk);

/* discretizing with van Loan (Alternative) */
VWVT: V. W.transpose(V);

G_tilde: -G$
for i: 1 thru length(VWVT[1]) do (G_tilde: addcol(G_tilde, args(transpose(VWVT)[i])))$
Gt: transpose(G)$

rowCount: length(Gt)$
columnCount: length(Gt[1])$
t: zeromatrix(rowCount, columnCount)$
for i: 1 thru columnCount do (t: addcol(t, args(transpose(Gt))[i]))$

for i: 1 thru length(t) do (G_tilde: addrow(G_tilde, args(t)[i]))$
G_tilde: G_tilde * dt;
domxexpt: false$
G_exp: matrixexp(G_tilde);

Gn_T: submatrix(1, length(G_exp) - length(G), G_exp, 1, length(G_exp) - length(G[1]) )$ /* lower right part of the matrix exponential matrixexp */
Gn: transpose(Gn_T);
Gn_invCv: submatrix(length(G_exp) - length(G) + 1, length(G_exp) , G_exp, 1, length(G_exp) - length(G[1]) ); /* upper right part of the matrix exponential matrixexp */

CV_n: Gn.Gn_invCv;

[1] Computing Integrals Involving the Matrix Exponential (https://www.olemartin.no/artikler/vanloan.pdf)
[2] Introduction to Random Signals and Applied Kalman Filtering - 4th_edition
[3] How to use Kalman filter for altitude prediction based on barometer data?
[4] https://personales.upv.es/asala/DocenciaOnline/material/DiscretizRuidoVanLoanEN.pdf
